# fgets()/sscanf for input works well in function. When fnct left and returned to, there is extra input/line in stdin?

Tags: c, fgets, scanf, c89

I realize similar questions have been asked, and answered. But after searching through them, I still haven't really found a solution to what I'm encountering.

Obviously I'm new to C.

I've read that fflush() is not good to use to flush the buffer, as it has undetermined results, depending on environment.

What I've got is a menu, that directs execution flow to a different function, which gets a choice from the user. This works successfully until, upon correct menu selection, execution flow is directed to another function, and then back to the main menu.

Here's what I've got...

```
int main ( void )
{
   Menu();

   return 0;
}

void Menu()
{
   printf( "\n" );
   printf( "1. Enter data\n" );
   printf( "2. Display data\n" );
   printf( "3. Quit\n" );

   ValidateChoice();

   return;
}

void ValidateChoice()
{
   char choice = '\0';

   do 
   {
      printf( "\nChoice: " );
      choice = GetChoice();
      switch (choice) 
      {
         case '1':
            EnterData();
            break;
         case '2':
            DisplayData();
            break;
         case '3':
            printf( "\nQuit\n" );
            break;
         default:
            break;
      }
      while (getchar() != '\n');
   } 
   while (choice != '3');
}

char GetChoice()
{
   char choice[CHOICE_LENGTH];
   char firstChar;

   fgets(choice, CHOICE_LENGTH, stdin); /*readline into string */
   sscanf(choice, "%c", &firstChar); /* get the first char of the string */

   return (firstChar);
}

void EnterData()
{
   printf( "\nEnterData() called\n" );
   Menu();

   return;
}

void DisplayData()
{
   printf( "\nDisplayData() called\n" );
   Menu();

   return;
}
```

If I don't call Menu() in EnterData() it works fine; continuing to prompt for a Selection (in getChoice()).

What can I do to allow flow out of GetChoice, into another function, and back to Menu() without having a bunch of characters left over in the buffer?

If someone could offer an explanation as to what I'm doing wrong, where I need to put additional loops to catch excess data, with an example or two, I would greatly appreciate it.

(Or point me in the direction of a post with the solution!)

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I don't think `switch (...) {...} while (...);` is what you want, unless you just mean to chew up any extraneous characters. If so, put the final `;` on a line by itself, or use `continue;`.

Comment: Try commenting out `while (getchar() != '\n');`

Comment: +1 for having done some research!

Comment: Where is DisplayData() ?, can you post it please

Comment: I added the DisplayData() function. I just omitted it initially, because neither it nor EnterData() do anything at this point (as I want to figure out this error first).

Admittedly this code was from something I saw on a forum.

I tried removing the while after the switch, and the same thing happens. Basically, however many times I go into either DisplayData() or EnterData(), I have to enter '3' (to quit) that many extra times, before the program actually terminates..

Comment: @JosephQuinsey, I think the logic behind the while(getchar() != '\n'); is, in fact to chew up any extraneous characters. My understanding (though likely erroneous) is that using fgets() will remove the end line character(?), but sscanf() will not/Will append a new line char?
I'm thinking it's this newline character that is messing up my GetChoice() when called the second/third time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to happen is that you're constantly calling new methods each time you make a choice, instead of returning to the first `Menu()` call, which in my opinion should be ideal.
We can follow the flow of execution to see this clearly.

Assuming that `main` calls `Menu`, we have:

```
main
  Menu
    ValidateChoice
      GetChoice (assume you return 1)
      EnterData
        Menu
          ValidateChoice
            GetChoice
            EnterData
              Menu
                  ....
```

This explains why you have to press 3 multiple times before finally exiting the program, or basically returning to main.

One approach to solve this issue would be to make your `ValidateChoice` return `1` or `0` (for valid choice or exit), and keep a loop in your `Menu` method to verify this.

For instance:

```
void Menu(void)
{
   do 
   {
       printf( "\n" );
       printf( "1. Enter data\n" );
       printf( "2. Display data\n" );
       printf( "3. Quit\n" );

   } while (ValidateChoice());

   return;
}
```

And have `ValidateChoice` as follows:

```
int ValidateChoice()
{
   char choice = '\0';

   printf( "\nChoice: " );
   choice = GetChoice();
   switch (choice) 
   {
      case '1':
         EnterData();
         break;
      case '2':
         DisplayData();
         break;
      case '3':
         printf( "\nQuit\n" );
         return 0;
      default:
         break;
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: This... makes perfect sense. And now I can see why I have to 'quit' so many times.
Unfortunately, upon implementing this, I still have the same results.
Also, part of my criteria is to not display the whole menu when an incorrect choice is entered, but just the 'choice:' prompt.
Understanding the logic of why I need to quit an extra time for every menu entered is very helpful though. This should help me figure out how to get around it.
Thanks you!

Comment: The problem is the trailing '\n' ? Did you try placing the while (getchar() != '\n'); at the end of the GetChoice() method, right before the return statement.

Comment: :/... It's there. Tried it with the fgets() and sscanf() within a do/while loop (getchar() != '\n'); as well.
I really appreciate your help. 
If/when I figure it out, I'll make sure to include the solution :).

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error. Could it be that your CHOICE_LENGTH is defined to 1? in that case the trailing '\n' will remain in the buffer after the input is read. fgets should read (and remove) the newline from stdin

Comment: CHOICE_LENGTH is defined as 2... 
I'll check the rest of my code (when I get home) and figure out what's going on. If it's working for you, then there must be an error somewhere else.
Once again, thanks!

Comment: I tested with CHOICE_LENGTH as 2 and got the repeated behaviour!! I assume that it is because '\n' is represented (in Windows I believe?) as CRLF, which is 2 bytes long. I hope this solves your issue as well :)

Comment: Your code allowed me to get it working as intended. (I'm not certain what I was doing wrong in other code; I changed tried so many changes)
Now I need to figure out how to get it to return to Menu() after a choice is made, but prompt only for 'choice:' if incorrect input is entered (eg 4, a, 0).
You've pointed me in the [very] right direction. Thanks Allbeert!

Answer (score 0):

***Try your code*** with the following modifications:  (see comments)  This mod allows selection of *3* to exit program.

***Note:*** Other debugging may be required for additional functionality

```
int     main()
{
    EnterData();
}

void Menu(void)
{
   printf( "\n" );
   printf( "1. Enter data\n" );
   printf( "2. Display data\n" );
   printf( "3. Quit\n" );

   ValidateChoice();

   return;
}

void ValidateChoice(void)
{
   char choice = '\0';

   //do   //remove two lines
   //{
      printf( "\nChoice: " );
      choice = GetChoice();
      switch (choice) 
      {
         case '1':
            EnterData();
            break;
         case '2':
            DisplayData();
            break;
         case '3':
            printf( "\nQuit\n" );
            break;
         default:
            break;
      //}  //remove two lines
      //while (getchar() != '\n');
   } 
   while (choice != '3');
}

char GetChoice(void)
{
   char choice[CHOICE_LENGTH];
   char firstChar;

   fgets(choice, CHOICE_LENGTH, stdin); /*readline into string */
   sscanf(choice, "%c", &firstChar); /* get the first char of the string */

   return (firstChar);
}

void EnterData(void)
{
   printf( "\nEnterData() called\n" );
   Menu();

   return;
}

void DisplayData(void)
{

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me either...
If I '3' (quit) upon initial entry to the menu/choice, it quits successfully. But after returning  from either Display/EnterData(), it will print 'quit', but not exit the loop. It will then continue to accept input, without triggering the switch...